# Filter out NaN of a list of duplicate items using pandas in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, duplicates, filtering, nan

I have a [set of real estate ad data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XUjqeXVgjZJ8jVNAn9MeIb9zHLhVj4mwRs-hk1P050o/edit?usp=sharing). Several of the lines are about the same real estate, so it's full of duplicates that aren't exactly the same. It looks like this :

```
    ID  URL CRAWL_SOURCE    PROPERTY_TYPE   NEW_BUILD   DESCRIPTION IMAGES  SURFACE LAND_SURFACE    BALCONY_SURFACE ... DEALER_NAME DEALER_TYPE CITY_ID CITY    ZIP_CODE    DEPT_CODE   PUBLICATION_START_DATE  PUBLICATION_END_DATE    LAST_CRAWL_DATE LAST_PRICE_DECREASE_DATE
0   22c05930-0eb5-11e7-b53d-bbead8ba43fe    http://www.avendrealouer.fr/location/levallois...   A_VENDRE_A_LOUER    APARTMENT   False   Au rez de chaussÃ©e d'un bel immeuble rÃ©cent,...   ["https://cf-medias.avendrealouer.fr/image/_87...   72.0    NaN NaN ... Lamirand Et Associes    AGENCY  54178039    Levallois-Perret    92300.0 92  2017-03-22T04:07:56.095 NaN 2017-04-21T18:52:35.733 NaN
1   8d092fa0-bb99-11e8-a7c9-852783b5a69d    https://www.bienici.com/annonce/ag440414-16547...   BIEN_ICI    APARTMENT   False   Je vous propose un appartement dans la rue Col...   ["http://photos.ubiflow.net/440414/165474561/p...   48.0    NaN NaN ... Proprietes Privees  MANDATARY   54178039    Levallois-Perret    92300.0 92  2018-09-18T11:04:44.461 NaN 2019-06-06T10:08:10.89  2018-09-25
...
```

I grouped the dataset making a list of duplicate items on `DESCRIPTION` column using pandas in python. However, it also grouped on the `NaN` as one can see at the end of the list. How to filter them out ?

```
>>> df[descriptions.isin(descriptions[descriptions.duplicated()])].sort_values("DESCRIPTION")

    ID  URL CRAWL_SOURCE    PROPERTY_TYPE   NEW_BUILD   DESCRIPTION IMAGES  SURFACE LAND_SURFACE    BALCONY_SURFACE ... DEALER_NAME DEALER_TYPE CITY_ID CITY    ZIP_CODE    DEPT_CODE   PUBLICATION_START_DATE  PUBLICATION_END_DATE    LAST_CRAWL_DATE LAST_PRICE_DECREASE_DATE
2152    87217310-c861-11e9-a6b2-651beb16710e    https://www.bienici.com/annonce/pericles-26784406   BIEN_ICI    APARTMENT   False   *** Appartement , Levallois, Anatole France **...   ["http://photo3.pericles.fr/photo_get.php?S1=6...   50.38   NaN NaN ... Samcoger    AGENCY  54178039    Levallois-Perret    92300.0 92  2019-08-26T22:37:46.192 NaN 2019-08-27T00:28:01.267 NaN
1810    d3ff1bf0-c849-11e9-a6b2-651beb16710e    https://www.meilleursagents.com/annonces/achat...   MEILLEURS_AGENTS    APARTMENT   False   *** Appartement , Levallois, Anatole France **...   ["http://thumbor.meilleursagents.com/vo8e7fykb...   50.00   NaN NaN ... SAMCOGER    AGENCY  54178039    Levallois-Perret    92300.0 92  2019-08-26T21:38:22.08  NaN 2019-08-26T21:38:22.08  NaN
1441    ea3e2720-c21e-11e9-9fab-c3006e339e11    https://www.meilleursagents.com/annonces/achat...   MEILLEURS_AGENTS    APARTMENT   False   121 rue Victor Hugo, 92300 LEVALLOIS, nous vou...   ["http://thumbor.meilleursagents.com/9211s4Up-...   35.00   NaN NaN ... BONJOUR OSCAR Bastille Saint Antoine    AGENCY  54178039    Levallois-Perret    92300.0 92  2019-08-19T01:16:04.093 NaN 2019-08-26T05:06:52.875 NaN
658 d93da9a0-c250-11e9-81e9-5f24299f2ef3    https://www.bienici.com/annonce/immo-facile-33...   BIEN_ICI    APARTMENT   False   121 rue Victor Hugo, 92300 LEVALLOIS, nous vou...   ["https://media.immo-facile.com/office5/bo_con...   35.00   NaN NaN ... Bonjour Oscar Bastille - Saint Antoine  AGENCY  54178039    Levallois-Perret    92300.0 92  2019-08-19T05:52:44.636 NaN 2019-08-26T18:50:37 NaN
...
278 053396e0-c004-11e9-9fab-c3006e339e11    https://immobilier.lefigaro.fr/annonces/annonc...   EXPLORIMMO  APARTMENT   False   NaN ["https://pix.yanport.com/ads/053396e0-c004-11...   44.00   NaN NaN ... NaN PRIVATE 54178039    Levallois-Perret    92300.0 92  2019-08-16T08:58:29.976 NaN 2019-08-23T11:03:00.487 NaN
1191    6f4df390-6541-11e9-adc1-59e67c527828    https://immobilier.lefigaro.fr/annonces/annonc...   EXPLORIMMO  APARTMENT   False   NaN ["https://pix.yanport.com/ads/6f4df390-6541-11...   30.00   NaN NaN ... NaN PRIVATE 54178039    Levallois-Perret    92300.0 92  2019-04-22T20:58:51.706 NaN 2019-08-13T17:48:23.92  NaN
```

I'm doing this because I want to keep only one line with all the `CRAWL_SOURCE` and remove all the other rows with duplicated `DESCRIPTION`.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want to remove duplicates on `DESCRIPTION`. This can be done simply by:

```
df[~df.duplicated('DESCRIPTION')]
```

If removes 249 duplicates from the original data set of 2164 rows.